# Share instances of an Eigen::Matrix with pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

I am using pybind11 to create python bindings for my C++ code. In C++ I have some classes that are sharing an `Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>` by having a `std::shared_ptr<>` to it.

The matrix itself is loaded and assigned to the different objects in python

```
matrix = scipy.io.mmread("C.mtx")

o1 = O1()
o2 = O2()
o1.matrix = matrix
o2.matrix = matrix
```

When I create my bindings, I try to receive a `std::shared_ptr<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>`, but pybind11 fails to compile

```
void VNCS::Sim2D::py::projection(pybind11::module &m)
{
    ::py::class_<VNCS::Sim2D::Projection, sofa::core::sptr<VNCS::Sim2D::Projection>>(m, "Projection")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def_property(
            "clusterMatrix",
            [](const VNCS::Sim2D::Projection &projection) { return projection.clusterMatrix(); },
            [](VNCS::Sim2D::Projection &projection, std::shared_ptr<Eigen::SparseMatrix<VNCS::Sim2D::Kernel::Real>> m) {
                projection.setClusterMatrix(m);
            });
}
```

with the following error

```
error: static assertion failed: Holder classes are only supported for custom types
```

What would be the best way to be able to share the matrix between the C++ classes and assign it from python?